# Problem in logging in as admin

Tags: multisite, errors

When I am trying  to login as admin to my site I am redirecting to another unknown page. The login page is  pointed to a page-Id2 .I don't understand why it is happened and how to solve it.

The links to admin page are redirecting to that page Id-12 .

Could any one help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved when I deactivated some plugins .

Answer (score 2):

My first recommendation would be to delete or rename your `.htaccess` file.  That file is what contains the guts of WordPress' redirection engine.  And that's also the only thing that could be redirecting from the login.

WordPress redirects *virtual* URLs to `http://blog.url/index.php` so that the blog can serve up content.  But the admin dashboard and login pages are *real* pages within the site ... not virtual URLs.  If you can't manually get to `http://blog.url/wp-admin/index.php` or `http://blog.url/wp-login.php` then that means something on the server side of things is preventing you from accessing WordPress ... `.htaccess` is the first place to look ... your actual server configuration would be the second.

Comment: Thanks for your help.A plugin named theme-my-login ( http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/)is causing the problem .All the sub-sites  of multisite Installations are redirecting to some other pages If I installed that plugin.

Comment: I got an answer from theme-my-login authors .They said that the plugin is not compatible with Multisite Installation .